# Python Why does my chart disappear when using matplotlip.pyplot.figure(figsize)

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyscript

When rendering matplotlib charts using pyscript and using figure(figsize) the chart disappears and replaces the x and y axes. Why is this happening?

[With figsize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sscVe.png)

[Without figsize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mknwe.png)

```
            import pandas as pd
            import numpy as np
            import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
            import seaborn as sns
            from pyodide.http import open_url

            url = open_url('../data/salaries.csv')
            df = pd.read_csv(url)

            df_no_outliers=df[(df.salary_in_usd>min) & (df.salary_in_usd&lt;max)]
            top_jobs=df_no_outliers.job_title.value_counts()[:7]

            plt.figure(2)
            barplot = sns.barplot(x='work_year', y='salary_in_usd', data=df_no_outliers)
            plt.tight_layout()
            plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
            plt
```

Comment: I could be mistaken, but you are esentially creating a new figure object by placeing it after the barplot. try putting the figsize before barplot

Comment: Your code should generate 2 figures. The [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html) states that a new figure is created if you don't give an integer or string which is the case with your second plt.figure.
You should use figsize directly with your first figure call:
`plt.figure(2, figsize(15, 8))`.

Comment: Ohh! Thank you, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks chitown and @Flow, this worked perfectly, thank you.